# Test an edit function in rest with mockito - Java EE - JUnit

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, junit, mockito

Currently I'm trying to work with Mockito combined with rest. I'm not sure how to test my edit method in rest with Mockito and rest. The last block of code contains the part I can't figure out atm. I haven't worked with Mockito before so all tips are welcome.

**This is the functionality i want to test:**

```
@POST
@Path("edit/{id}")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Profile editProfile(Profile profile, @PathParam("id") Long id){
    Profile updatedProfile = profileService.getProfile(id);
    updatedProfile.setBiography(profile.getBiography());
    updatedProfile.setLocation(profile.getLocation());
    updatedProfile.setWebsite(profile.getWebsite());
    updatedProfile.setAvatar(profile.getAvatar());
    updatedProfile.setImage(profile.getImage());
    updatedProfile.setUpdated_at(new Date());
    return updatedProfile;
}
```

**Setting up my TestClass here**

```
Client client;
WebTarget root;
static final String PATH = "/MyApp/api/profile/";
static final String BASEURL = "http://localhost:8080" + PATH;
List<Profile> profileList = new ArrayList<Profile>();
Profile profile;

@Mock
ProfileDao profileDao;

@InjectMocks
private ProfileService profileService;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    this.client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    this.root = this.client.target(BASEURL);
    profile = new Profile(1L,"biography", "location" ,"website","../avatar.jpg","../image.jpg" );
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        profileList.add(profile);
    }
}
```

**The Test function to edit an test: /profile/edit/1 - /profile/edit/{id}**

```
// This part doesn't work. I'm not sure how to handle this part with mockito and rest

@Test
public void editProfileTest() { 
    String mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON;        
    when(profileDao.find(1L)).thenReturn(new Profile(1L,"biography", "location" ,"website", "../avatar.jpg","../image.jpg"));
    final Entity<Profile> entity = Entity.entity(profileService.getProfile(1L), mediaType);

    Profile profileResult = this.root.path("edit/1").request().post(entity, Profile.class);
    assertThat(profileResult, is(profile)); // this doesn't match
}
```

Comment: Do you want to create an integration test (where test the combination of your method, the service, the dao, the database)? Or do you want to to test only the method? Since the method only reads the Profile and updates 6 attributes I would test that (if I don't want to create an integration test).

Comment: @NiklasP the question is about testing the method only. However I'm also interested in an integration test. I've found out the solution for the method only test, I will post it below as answer. If you have any reference or solution for an integration test I would be also interested for that.

Comment: The problem of the `is(profile)` part of your JUnit test is that `is` compares the pointer/addresses of the profile objects if they are the **same** (equal isn't enough) and your mocked method creates a **new** Profile which means equal but **not** the same. The easiest way would be to return the defined profile with `when(profileDao.find(1L)).thenReturn(profile);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I wasn't really sure how to make the test valid but with the following piece of code I solved my problem.

**Adjusted my Rest / Mockito test a little bit:**

```
@Test
public void editProfileTest() { 
    String mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON;        
    when(profileDao.find(2L)).thenReturn(profileList.get(0));
    final Entity<Profile> entity = Entity.entity(profileService.getProfile(2L), mediaType);
    Profile profileResult = this.root.path("edit/2").request().post(entity, Profile.class);
    assertThat(profileResult.getId(), is(profileService.getProfile(2L).getId()));
    assertThat(profileResult.getUser_id(), is(profileService.getProfile(2L).getUser_id()));
    assertThat(profileResult.getAvatar(), is(profileService.getProfile(2L).getAvatar()));
    assertThat(profileResult.getBiography(), is(profileService.getProfile(2L).getBiography()));
    assertThat(profileResult.getLocation(), is(profileService.getProfile(2L).getLocation()));
    assertThat(profileResult.getWebsite(), is(profileService.getProfile(2L).getWebsite()));
    assertThat(profileResult.getImage(), is(profileService.getProfile(2L).getImage()));
}
```

This is testing the method on /**MyApp/profile/edit/{id}** only. If you have examples for an integration test or references feel free to post about it. As I'm trying to learn some more about testing in general.

Comment: If you don't want to test your `profileService`, then I would mock the method `profileService.getProfile(2L)` and would let the mock return a defined profiled which I then would compare to the `profileResult`.